# running two process simultaneously

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run 2 processes simultaneously, but only the first one runs

```
def add():
    while True:
        print (1)
        time.sleep(3)

def sud():
     while True:
        print(0)
        time.sleep(3)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=add) 
p1.run()
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=sud)
p.run()
```

Comment: Oh hey, it's this bug again. The `start`/`run` name choices have caused so many headaches over the years.

Comment: @user2357112 If it's common, surely there's a dupe?

Comment: @jpmc26: Likely, but I didn't find one in a quick search for `Python multiprocessing start run`.

Comment: @user2357112 Found one that has an answer describing the difference: [Python multiprocessing.Process: start with local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703083/python-multiprocessing-process-start-with-local-variable). Or maybe we need a better written/flushed out one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below will work for sure but try to run this as a module.Don't try in console or Jupiter notebook as notebook will never satisfy the condition "if **name** == '**main**'".
Save the entire code in a file say process.py and run it from command prompt.
Edit - 
It's working fine. Just now I tried - [image]

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def add():
    while True:
        print (1)
        time.sleep(3)

def sud():
     while True:
        print(0)
        time.sleep(3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=add)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='p', target=sud)
    p1.start()
    p.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is `start`, not `run`. `start` starts the process and calls `run` to perform the work in the new process; if you call `run`, you run the work in the calling process instead of a new process.

Comment: start() does nothing.

Comment: @YashwantSingh: Are you on Windows? If so, `start` seems to do nothing because you have another bug: you didn't use an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, which is mandatory to use `multiprocessing` on Windows due to a lack of `fork`.

Comment: @YashwantSingh: Then there must be a problem in some part of your code or your development environment that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I've edited the code pls see to it, this time with start(), but still only first one executes. using Windows , anaconda

Comment: @YashwantSingh: I don't see the edit you're referring to.

Comment: @YashwantSingh: Why did you move the process creation and `start` calls into `add` and `sud`?

Comment: because nothing was happening in main()

Comment: Well, you've screwed up your code in yet another way by doing that.

Comment: I'm rolling the code back to its original form, since the new version is wrong in an entirely different way that belongs in a new question.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think the new version would be a good question, either.